# Change background color of tmux pane depending on remote hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, iterm2

If I ssh into a remote server from tmux in a single pane, is it possible to change the background color of the pane based on the server name?

Let's say all my prod servers start with `prod_XYZ` and a dev server starts with `dev_XYZ.` If I ssh into these two servers, can I color them differently based on the type of server I am on? That is, based on the server prefix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I ssh into these two servers, can I color them differently based on the type of server I am on?

Yes.

My basic solution requires a wrapper for `ssh` (this may be a shell function or a script), plus an additional helper script.

---

The wrapper function should be like this:

```
ssh() {
  helper="$HOME/bin/_ssh_tmux_background"
  command ssh \
    -o PermitLocalCommand=yes \
    -o LocalCommand="'$helper' '%h'" \
    "$@"
  "$helper"
}
```

And this is the helper script:

```
#/bin/sh

[ -z "$TMUX_PANE" ] && exit
style=default
case "$1" in
    prod_* )
        style='bg=red'
        ;;
    dev_* )
        style='bg=blue'
        ;;
esac   
tmux select-pane -P "$style" -t "$TMUX_PANE"
```

Save the script where `$helper` in the function points to (`$HOME/bin/_ssh_tmux_background` in my code), make it executable.

Now if you invoke `ssh`, the function will run the actual `ssh` command with two additional options: `PermitLocalCommand` and `LocalCommand` (see `man 5 ssh_config` for details). This way you will run the helper script with the remote hostname as a sole argument as soon as you log into the remote host.

If you're in `tmux`, the script will inherit the `TMUX_PANE` environment variable. The script will exit immediately if outside of `tmux`, so it shouldn't interfere even if you use the function without `tmux`.

The script matches the remote hostname against your prefixes and picks the desired style for `tmux`. You are not limited to `case`, you can build your logic in any way you want (including regex matching with `[[`, but you need `bash` then, change the shebang). At the end the style is applied.

After `ssh` exits, the function calls the script without arguments. `"$1"` evaluates to an empty string which matches none of our patterns, so the default style of `default` is passed to `tmux`.

---

Note you can specify `PermitLocalCommand` and `LocalCommand` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or in `~/.ssh/config`. You cannot get rid of the wrapper so easily though, because you need to change the background color again after `ssh` exits.

Still a wrapperless solution may be desired. Imagine a script (invoked with `LocalCommand`) that retrieves its parent's (`ssh`'s) PID, forks to the background (so `ssh` continues), monitors the PID and restores `tmux` settings after `ssh` exits. Such script might *save* the original style of the pane, no matter what it was, and restore it later, instead of using the `default` style.

Let's do it. This is my attempt:

```
#/bin/sh

[ -z "$TMUX_PANE" ] && exit
[ "$#" -eq 1 ] || exit 1

newstyle="$1"
oldstyle="$(tmux select-pane -g -t "$TMUX_PANE")"

tmux select-pane -P "$newstyle" -t "$TMUX_PANE"

( tail --pid="$PPID" -f /dev/null
  tmux select-pane -P "$oldstyle" -t "$TMUX_PANE" ) &
```

The new script (say `$HOME/bin/_ssh_tmux_style`) should be executable as well. It uses `tail --pid` which is not portable; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058047/10765659) for alternative approaches.

Now we don't need the old wrapper function (so start a new shell or `unset -f ssh`). All we need is `~/.ssh/config`. Remember `man 5 ssh_config` says:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

Having this in mind place the following in the right place in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host prod_*
PermitLocalCommand=yes
LocalCommand="$HOME/bin/_ssh_tmux_style" 'bg=red'

Host dev_*
PermitLocalCommand=yes
LocalCommand="$HOME/bin/_ssh_tmux_style" 'bg=blue'
```

The double-quotes are important. Note the whole additional configuration (styles) is now embedded in the config of `ssh`. Make your `$PATH` contain `$HOME/bin` and then it gets even better:

```
LocalCommand=_ssh_tmux_style 'bg=red'
```

I find it quite elegant.